# strtok is using wrong delimiter (space as well as ",")

Tags: c++, ifstream, strtok

Is there a way to make strtok() not interpret spaces as separators?
I'm reading from .csv file, and my code has:

```
ifstream inf("file.csv");
char *n, *a, *b;
char n1[80], a1[80], b1[80], temp[80];
inf >> temp;
n = strtok(temp, ",");
strcpy(n1, n);
a = strtok(NULL, ",");
strcpy(a1, a);
b = strtok(NULL, ",");
strcpy(b1, b);
cout << a1 << " " << b1 << endl;
```

File contents:

```
123,San Francisco, Los Angeles
```

I think strtok interprets space as '\n' but I don't know how to ignore it.
I tried putting inf.ignore(' ') but doesn't work and gives me some random values. If, however, I change my file to 123,San_Francisco, Los_Angeles
then the program works. 
How could I ignore spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't blame `strtok`, its `ifstream` which stops extracting when finding a *whitespace* character. You should use one of the `getline()` variants if you want to read an entire line.

Comment: Agreed. If you're doing c++ and the homework is about reading .csv and not about the strtok function, then use getline and use temp.find_first_of or temp.find_first_not_of.

Comment: If you are entering a comment on stackoverflow and you hit enter, you're going to have a bad time. :)

Comment: The problem is that we must you strtok. It doesn't say that cannot use getline though so I'll probaly use it.